# Error When Printing a Large Number, Min and Sec Become Negative

Tags: java

I am getting an error when printing a large number, minutes and seconds become negative. I think it is due to the size of the number that is printing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minutes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //User information
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number of hours, days, weeks or years: ");
        int s = in.nextInt();

        //Compute input
        int hours = s * 60;
        int days = s * 1440;
        int weeks = s * 10080;
        int years = s * 525600;

        //Print results
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Here are your results!");
        System.out.println("If you entered hours, this is the number of minutes" + ": " + hours);
        System.out.println("If you entered days, this is the number of minutes" + ": " + days);
        System.out.println("If you entered weeks, this is the number of minutes" + ": " + weeks);
        System.out.println("If you entered years, this is the number of minutes" + ": " + years);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I think it is due to the size of the number that is printing" yes, you are observing integer overflow. If `int` size is not enough consider using `long`, or `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly it, you are having a `integer overflow`, when that happens, java starts the count from the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` that why i shows negative, convert it to `long` ant it should be fine.